# OData 4.0 External Object: Can't execute SOQL using IN or EQUALS operator, only LIKE - Bug or bad documentation?

Tags: soql, lightning-connect, externalobjects, odata

According to the Salesforce documentation on [SOQL Limits on Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_limits.htm?_ga=2.19689784.1490328048.1705425558-113074820.1663592342):

> External objects also don’t support the following.
>
> - EXCLUDES operator
> - FOR VIEW clause
> - FOR REFERENCE clause
> - INCLUDES operator
> - LIKE operator
> - toLabel() function
> - TYPEOF clause
> - WITH clause

However, I've found an existing query against an External object in our Org (Sales_Order__x) which uses the LIKE operator (Code modified for privacy):

```
for ( Sales_Order__x sOrder :
                [   SELECT  StringVal__c, FieldA, FieldB,
                            FieldC, ETC
                    FROM    Sales_Order__x
                    WHERE   (   StringVal__c LIKE :number_pre
                            AND StringVal__c LIKE :number_post
                            )
                    ORDER BY FieldA 
                    LIMIT 1
                ]
                )
            { // Loop code removed }
```

This query works, despite documentation that suggests it should not. Attempting to query this same object using `IN` or `=` operators however results in an error.

### **Examples:**

```
SELECT StringVal__c FROM Sales_Order__x WHERE StringVal__c =:singleStringVal
```

**Results In:**
System.ExternalObjectException: data.api.DataSourceConnectionException: The external system responded with an HTTP error "400 Bad Request". The system tried to reach this URL: https://odata-2-virginia.heroku.com/odata/v4/**_REMOVED_**/SALES$ORDER?%24top=2001&%24filter=StringVal%20eq%20%271086251%27&%24count=true&%24select=StringVal%2Cunique_row_id

---

```
SELECT StringVal__c FROM Sales_Order__x WHERE StringVal__c IN :stringCollection
```

**Results In:**
System.ExternalObjectException: data.api.DataSourceConnectionException: The external system responded with an HTTP error "400 Bad Request". The system tried to reach this URL: https://odata-2-virginia.heroku.com/odata/v4/**_REMOVED_**/SALES$ORDER?%24top=2001&%24filter=StringVal%20eq%20%271234%27%20or%20StringVal%20eq%20%2712345%27&%24count=true&%24select=StringVal%2Cunique_row_id

---

This leads me to believe either the SOQL Limits on Objects documentation is outdated or incomplete, or that there is some other underlying reason why I can't execute queries against this OData 4 External Object with the expected operators that I'm missing. Which one is it?

Comment: _Which one is it?_ - could be all three. OData supports [predicates](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#queryData). Whether SF has implemented them correctly and/or the target OData Provider does the right thing and/or the SF doc is correct...are all good questions. Recommend getting in touch with SF product support.